# can't run python modules

Tags: python, module

for example I want to use pymatrix module
I install it and when I want to use I see this err:

```
 C:\Users\my-user> pymatrix
pymatrix : The term 'pymatrix' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pymatrix
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pymatrix:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

how to fix?

I tried to use pymatrix and so other modules and got that err

Comment: I assume you meant to do this inside python code, not at a command prompt...

Comment: `pymatrix` is a module. When you install it you can import it in your Python script and use it. It's not meant to run as a stand-alone software.